# CiviBanking - Skip certain payment entries when importing

Tags: civibanking

Use Case: The bank statement might contain some payments, that should NOT AT ALL get into CiviCRM (e.g. salary payments).

Is there an easy way to make the importer plugin skip certain lines?

Best
Detlev

Comment: Thanks for drawing my attention to Civibanking - looks very useful. From a quick look at the user guide https://docs.civicrm.org/banking/en/latest/user-guide/ the Analysing Stage gives an example of "the payment has nothing to do with CiviCRM" which is what I think you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, this would work, but in this case is not enough: The bank statements contain some payments, that should never be stored within CiviCRM because they shall not be visible to unauthorized people. (i.e. CiviCRM users with access to CiviContribute and CiviBanking, but with no access to salary information).

Comment: Looking a bit more at the extension, I don't think its possible. CiviBanking is an extension to CiviCRM so if you really don't want it in CiviCRM at all then you will need it before importing the file. A quick look at the extension doesn't seem to have any speciific CiviBanking permissions so you can't limit to a specific user, which might be acceptable. But someone properly familiar with the extension may know more so I won't call this a answer yet. Hope there is a way.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you're talking about the CSV importer, there is a configuration option called `line_filter` where you can provide a regular expression to skip a line if it doesn't match it. The "line" given to `preg_match()` is a standardized csv string. See [here](https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking/blob/0.7/extension/CRM/Banking/PluginImpl/Importer/CSV.php#L128-L135).

Additionally, there's also another (and even older) line filter mechanism based on the `filter` attribute, see [here](https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking/blob/0.8-alpha8/extension/CRM/Banking/PluginImpl/Importer/CSV.php#L275-L288). However this approach has mostly been abandoned in favour of the more flexible `regex` based approach. However, it's still in the code for backwards compatibility, and there are still examples using it, see e.g. [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/banking/en/latest/configuration/plugins/importers/csv/).

Comment: Great - this is what I was searching for!

Comment: The solution is not obvious - therefore some more detail here:

1. Using the regex approach ("filter") is a good idea!
2. We have to set a regex filter for two kind of lines:
    a) The lines that should be imported
    b) The heading line!
3. Be aware, that the heading might contain the character ";" , which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this, is to operate with two bank accounts. One that is processed in CiviCRM, and one for transactions that normally shouldn’t be processed in CiviCRM. Only have the first one as bank files, and then you have solve it